# Type/Value Mismatch error while declaring a vector of custom class in c++

Tags: c++, vector, type-mismatch

In my header file, I have a custom class called `Arc` declared like this

```
class Arc{
public:
    Point start, end, centre;
    //an arc is specified with its centre , starting point and end point

    float radius, sweep, theta;
    //radius of the arc and the angle enclosed by the arc are specified

    int direction;
    //whether the arc is formed in the clockwise direction or the anticlockwise direcn is specfied

    Arc();
    Arc(Point, Point, Point, int);

    void draw();
    // draws the arc on the GLUT canvas

    int nextDirection(Point);
    // finds the direction of the arc formed by joining the end point of this arc and a new point
};
```

I want to create a vector of this custom class . I declare a vector like this:

```
extern vector<Arc> arcs;
```

This line gives the following 4 errors.

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector'|
error:   expected a type, got 'Arc'|
error: template argument 2 is invalid|
error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token|
```

I read on another answer that such a declaration needs a default constructor inside the class which i have added. but still same errors occur

**Note:** It builds successfully on Ubuntu14.04 using `g++` compiler. But when trying to build in Code::Blocks on Windows 8.1 using `mingw-g++` it gives this error.

Comment: Did you include `.h` file with your class before declaring the vector?

Comment: If you did include the .h file, did you put `Arc` in a namespace you're omitting when creating the `vector`?

Comment: Also forward declaration might help, but again, make sure you have included `.h` file with your class and you got implementations for all methods from class.

Comment: @tema @TonyD `Arc` class and `vector` declaration are in the same header file one after th other

Comment: Your code compiles fine in mingw of http://www.onlinecompiler.net/ Double check that `Arc` is defined *before* `arcs` and that there is no circular header dependencies in headers.

Comment: @user2079303 code compiles on ubuntu too... should I assume its a problem with Code:Blocks or windows?

Comment: @udiboy1209 well, since it worked fine on that site, the problem probably isn't windows. In theory, it could be the way you've configured C:B to call the compiler. I find that unlikely to cause error like this, but you can compare the compilation commands on ubuntu and windows and see if they're different. Purely guessing, I postulate that you have broken pre-processor macros.

Comment: @user2079303 I changed the class name to `Arca` everywhere and it worked :P